# Delete untagged images on Google Cloud Registry

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-container-registry

When we push repeatedly into `gcr.io` with the same image name and a version (tag), there is a high number of untagged images.
Is there a simple way to remove all untagged images for a single image using the `gcloud` CLI tool to avoid incurring Storage costs?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/project-id/repository --format=json --limit=unlimited` will give you an easily consumable json blob of info for images in a repo (such as digests w/ associated tags).

In order to *just* enumerate all digests which lack tags:

`gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/project-id/repository --filter='-tags:*'  --format='get(digest)' --limit=unlimited`

Which you can iterate over and delete with:
`gcloud container images delete --quiet gcr.io/project-id/repository@DIGEST`

Answer (score 10):

Handy when you glue them together with awk and xargs

`gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/${IMAGE} --filter='-tags:*' --format='get(digest)' --limit=unlimited | awk '{print "gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/${IMAGE}@" $1}' | xargs gcloud container images delete --quiet`

Answer (score 6):

The previous one-liner was not working for me. I am using this one at the moment:

- Deletes all the un-tagged images for a given PROJECT_ID and IMAGE
- Uses Xargs -I, which creates a token (called {arg} in this case)

```
gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/${IMAGE} \
    --filter='-tags:*' --format='get(digest)' --limit=unlimited |\
  xargs -I {arg} gcloud container images delete \
    "gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/${IMAGE}@{arg}" --quiet
```

Comment: Thanks, the other answer wasn't working for me either on my bash shell because the ENV var wasn't interpolating within single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

My use case was to delete all untagged images from a specific project. I wrote simple script to achieve this:

```
delete_untagged() {
    echo "   |-Deleting untagged images for $1"
    while read digest; do
       gcloud container images delete $1@$digest --quiet 2>&1 | sed 's/^/        /'
    done < <(gcloud container images list-tags $1 --filter='-tags:*' --format='get(digest)' --limit=unlimited)
}

delete_for_each_repo() {
    echo "|-Will delete all untagged images in $1"
    while read repo; do
        delete_untagged $repo
    done < <(gcloud container images list --repository $1 --format="value(name)")
}

delete_for_each_repo gcr.io/<project-id>/<repository>
```

The full script can be found here: https://gist.github.com/lahsivjar/2b011d69368a26af7043d4aa70ec78f8

Hope it will be helpful to someone

Answer (score 1):

It is documented *[here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/images/delete)* but one important thing to be noted is that

> DIGEST must be of the form "`sha256:<digest>`"

So catch first the form `sha256:<digest>` of untagged images

```
$ DIGEST=`gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE] \
--filter='-tags:*' --format='get(digest)'`
$ echo $DIGEST
sha256:7c077a9ca45aea7134d8436a3071aceb5fa62758cc86eadec63f02692b7875f7
```

Then use the variable to remove it

```
$ gcloud container images delete --quiet gcr.io/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE]@$DIGEST
Digests:
- gcr.io/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE]@sha256:7c077a9ca45a......
Deleted [gcr.io/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE]@sha256:7c077a9ca45a......].
```

Answer (score 1):

**Powershell** version of the one liner posted by @Benos

```
gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/myprojectname/myimagename --filter='-tags:*' --format='get(tags)' --limit=unlimited | ForEach-Object { gcloud container images delete "gcr.io/myprojectname/myimagename:$PSItem" --quiet }
```

Remove the `--filter='-tags:*'` to delete all tags of a certain image (this is what I was trying to accomplish)

Comment: Had to change : to @ to get it to work: gcr.io/myprojectname/myimagename@$PSItem

Answer (score 0):

Corrected Powershell Command

```
gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/myprojectname/myimagename --filter='-tags:*' --format='get(digest)' --limit=unlimited | ForEach-Object { gcloud container images delete "gcr.io/myprojectname/myimagename@$PSItem" --quiet }
```